# ActivityNotFoundException (MapActivity)

Tags: android, dictionary, mapactivity

i have an MapActivity in my application. I included it at my manifest file but when i run the application , everything runs fine except the MapActivity, Whenever i try to start MapActivity by clicking a Button it gives the following errors,

```
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xtreme.iSenegal/java.util.Map}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:2473)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:277)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.xtreme.iSenegal.Activity1.replaceContentView(Activity1.java:28)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.xtreme.iSenegal.Details$2.onClick(Details.java:94)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-02 18:06:39.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong with my MapActivity? Why is it not found?

My MapActivity's Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
```

public class Map extends MapActivity {

```
ArrayList<ListCellInfo> mapsearchresults=new ArrayList<ListCellInfo>();

MapView mapView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
MapController myMapController;

MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();

public static int flag=0;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    final EditText SearchForMap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextmap);

    Button bckbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retourmap);
    bckbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Details.back_activity_flag == 1) {

                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForMap.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Details.class);
                Activity1.group.replaceContentView("Details", myIntent);

            }
            else if (Details.back_activity_flag == 2) {

                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForMap.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Details.class);
                Activity2.group.replaceContentView("Details", myIntent);

            }
            else if (Details.back_activity_flag == 3) {

                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForMap.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Details.class);
                Activity3.group.replaceContentView("Details", myIntent);

            }

        }
    });

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_pin_img);
    MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

    /*Log.v("Details Lattitude",(int)(Details.lattitude* 1e6)+"");
    Log.v("Details Longitude",(int)(Details.longitude* 1e6)+"");*/

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Details.lattitude* 1e6),(int)(Details.longitude* 1e6));

    mapView.setFocusable(true);
    myMapController = mapView.getController();
    myMapController.animateTo(point);
    myMapController.setZoom(18);
    myMapController.setCenter(point);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, Details.name, "");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

    mapView.setStreetView(true);


    RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutmap);
    relativelayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForMap.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    });

    final MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay1=itemizedoverlay;

    Button searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbuttonmap);
    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForMap.getWindowToken(), 0);

            String getSearchText = SearchForMap.getText().toString();

            if(getSearchText.length()!=0){

                String[] fav=getSearchText.split(",");

                try {

                    /** Handling XML */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                    /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */

                    InputStream inputFile;

                    SharedPreferences flag = getSharedPreferences(iSenegal.Flag, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String getFlag = flag.getString("Flag", "");

                    if(getFlag.equals("0"))
                        inputFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.alldata);
                    else
                        inputFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/alldata.xml"));

                    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(inputFile));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);

                }

                for(int i=0;i<fav.length;i++){

                    for(int j=0;j<myXMLHandler.results.size();j++){

                        if(myXMLHandler.results.get(j).getSearchTag().toLowerCase().contains(fav[i].toLowerCase()))
                          mapsearchresults.add(myXMLHandler.results.get(j));

                    }
                }
                myXMLHandler.results.clear();

                if(!mapView.getOverlays().isEmpty()) 
                { 
                    mapOverlays.clear();
                    itemizedoverlay1.mOverlays.clear();
                    mapView.invalidate();

                }

                if(mapsearchresults.size()>0){

                    GeoPoint cpoint = new GeoPoint((int)(14.745335 * 1e6),(int)(-17.42157 * 1e6));

                    mapView.setFocusable(true);
                    myMapController = mapView.getController();
                    myMapController.animateTo(cpoint);
                    myMapController.setZoom(7);
                    myMapController.setCenter(cpoint);

                    for(int k=0;k<mapsearchresults.size();k++){

                        GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint((int)((mapsearchresults.get(k).getLatitude())* 1e6),(int)((mapsearchresults.get(k).getLongitude())* 1e6));
                        OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, mapsearchresults.get(k).getName(), "");

                        itemizedoverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
                        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay1);

                    }
                    mapView.invalidate();
                    mapsearchresults.clear();

                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

My Manifest File's Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.x.iSenegal"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".iSenegal"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Activity1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Activity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Activity3" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Activity4" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Activity5" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Categories" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Results" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Details" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Favoris" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Recherche" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="SearchResults" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Map" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using google add-on for map activity(for maps you should use google add-on),check whether you are using it or not.If you are using check do u have the line "import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;" in your source code instead "java.util.Map",Map and MapActivity both are different.can you post code snippet for more information.

Comment: Yes , i have added import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity; Anyways , I am giving my MapActivity's code above.

Comment: Hey,you named the activity class with the name "Map",so it assumes the Map as in java.util package instead of your.package.Map,so try to change the name of activity or try to give the complete package path in Intent object as Intent intent=new Intent(context,your.package.Map.class) and in Activity1 you will find the "import java.util.Map" remove it if do not use

Comment: Thanks a lot ... The name change strategy worked .... The problem was in the class which was calling MapActivity. That class took "Map" as in java.util.package instead of my package's Map. Anyways , thanks again for your help, really appreciate that .... :D